google-chrome-stable : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
Have started getting this error while trying to build my docker image that install google chrome stable.
google-chrome-stable : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
I did not get this when i ran it last month which indicates something has changed either on googles end or on ubuntu.
The part in my dockerfile that install google chrome is pasted below
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | \
    tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | \
    apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable jq net-tools xvfb apt-transport-https dirmngr \


Which version of Ubuntu is this Dockerfile based on?

solved this by installing gcc version 10
RUN wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
RUN wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb


I faced the same problem when installing google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
By referring below guideline, I also sovled this problem
https://github.com/f4exb/sdrangel/issues/524#issuecomment-646966704
Install add-apt-repository if you don't already have it:
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get update

Install gcc-10:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-10


It's not an exact duplicate, but I prefer the similar answer by Ameeto Castell who answered his own question because his answer does not add a new software repository. Instead it installs gcc-10 directly which is a better choice from the standpoint of package management.

Node image for Dockerfile
RUN wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
RUN wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

We were using node:14 as base image and installing google-chrome-stable unto that image, it seems node:14 was using debian-10 which didn't had libgcc-s1 so following answers from Jack wright i tried building from node:14-bullseye which is built on top of debian-11 which had gcc and libgcc-s1 available in it.
This solved my issue of libgcc-s1 package not installable.

I used node:16, updating for: FROM node:16-bullseye-slim worked after I also add libgcc-s1, but not ideal for me since I dont want to change de base image

I don't think you need to install libgcc-s1 specifically as it is already there in its packages,  you can check in docker hub

The solution for me was my Docker container base image was outdated, an upgrade fixed this issue.
I presume later I will will get a similar error, so I will definitely keep an eye on my image versions before resorting to manual package upgrades in the build.

Can those who are downvoting leave a comment here as to what can be improved about this answer? Thanks.
